# Value of no input? PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

So I am creating a form that has a bunch of number input fields. A user who's using may not input values into all of them and therefore I want to make conditions for that.

Example Code:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="any" name="test">
$test = $_POST['test'];
```

What is the value of `$test` when the form is submitted? I had originally thought it was "null" but it wasn't.

Comment: All sent in form values are strings (or arrays containing strings).

Comment: Just use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check them rather than checking for null (though you may want to do some javascript/client side checking as well, and avoid the server call)

Answer (score 3):

It will contain no value:

```
if (empty($_POST['test'])) {
    echo 'test contains no value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an empty string. NULL is absolutely nothing--not even a string. Empty input is still a string, but it just doesn't hold any content. It's confusing, but very different!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to check the value(containing the value type) from the form.

Answer (score 0):

The content of an empty form field is equivalent to `""` if you'd prefer to compare it like this.